# Merging tags [blog] and [blogs]

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Both [blog](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) and [blogs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogs) cover the same subject, so should be merged.

Comment: [tag:blogging] too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has now been completed.

All questions with the [blogs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogs) tag and [blogging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blogging) tag have now been converted to the [blog](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) tag and a synonym has been created.